# quicksort doesn't sort string with many letters

Tags: java, string, sorting, char, quicksort

I've been trying to do a program that sorts characters from a string in alphabetical order.
It works with short words, but when I tried to input word such as : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. It doesn't sort it at all.
Can somebody help me to improve my code?
Here is my code:

```
public class quicky{
public static void partition(char[] a,int low, int high){

    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    char tmp;

    int pivot = i+(j-i)/2;

    while (i <= j) {
      while(a[i] < a[pivot]){
        i++;
      }
      while(a[j] > a[pivot]){
        j--;
      }

      if(i <= j) {
        tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
      }
    }

    if(low < j){
      partition(a, low, j);
    }
    if(i < high){
      partition(a, i,high);
    }
  }
public Character[] toCharArray( String s )
{
   int len = s.length();
   Character[] array = new Character[len];
   for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
      array[i] = new Character(s.charAt(i));
   }
   return array;
}
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String output = quicksort(input);
        System.out.print(output);
    }
    public static String quicksort(String y)
    {
        int length = y.length();
        int i = 0;
        int j = length-1;
        char[] a = y.toCharArray();
        partition(a,i,j);
        String x=new String(a);
        return x;

    }
}
```

Comment: you know String has a built in [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()), right? Also, bonus points for `int pivot = i+(j-i)/2;` but you're not going to run into 32 bit integer overflow here, just go with `i+j/2` =)

Comment: First rule for this type of situation: Step through your code in an IDE debugger (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc). 99% of the time you will easily find the problem yourself and learn something in the process.  The 1% of the time where you can't figure it out, explain in detail what you found out during single-stepping and what you don't understand.  About 70% of the time after writing the explanation you will find the problem.  SO is for posting problems AFTER you've exhausted the obvious tactics, not as a first line of inquiry.  That's just wasting everybody's time.

Comment: Jim Garrison. Of course I tried something like this. I tried doing it with Jeliot, but it crashes with an error : Feature is not yet implemented. In console cmd it works..

Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I tried it as well, but it didn't work. Is it possible to use long instead int somehow in this case?

Comment: In while (a[i]) loop, i could become == pivot. THen in the "if (i<=j)" clause, i could become pivot+1 ... this should not be allowed.